# constructibility of heptagon from with straight edge, compass and angle trisector

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Angle trisector can be described from root of cubic $4x^3-3x=k$ for some constructible number $k$. The root of equation $x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$ are $2\cos (2 \pi/7), 2\cos (4 \pi/7)$ and $2\cos (6 \pi/7)$. How can be describe the construction of regular heptagon algebraically if roots of $4x^3-3x=k$ were constructible? Do those two cubics share root for some choice of constructible $k$? It has already been [discussed geometrically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/can-a-regular-heptagon-be-constructed-using-a-compass-straightedge-and-angle-t?rq=1), but I don't seem to know the algebraic approach.

Comment: Can you not derive it by working through the geometry? That would seem to be the most straightforward way, since there's only one angle being trisected in the linked post and it looks straightforward to describe...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes I can, but still, it would really be nice if we can describe the roots in terms of trisector polynomial.

Comment: Can the following be of help? http://math2.uncc.edu/~frothe/3181alleuclid1_16.pdf

Comment: @SantoshLinkha You must be careful here that $|k| \leq 1$, otherwise it does not make sense to trisect an angle (because cosine of an angle is always between 1 and -1.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straightforward

1. Get rid of the quadratic term (=depress the cubic). Let $x=u-1/3$ and we get $$u^3-\frac73u-\frac7{27}=0.$$
2. Scale it correctly to get that $[4:-3]$ ratio for the coefficients of the cubic/linear terms. Let $u=2\sqrt 7v/3$ and arrive at
   $$\frac{14\sqrt7}{27}\left(4v^3-3v-\frac1{2\sqrt7}\right)=0.$$

As $1/2\sqrt7$ is constructible, the angle trisector gives you $v$, then linear substitutions with constructible coefficients give you $u$ and $x$.