# Clarify a solution about Ruler-and-compass construction

Tags: field-theory, geometric-construction

I study about Ruler-and-compass construction.

I read this post :[Can a regular heptagon be constructed using a compass, straightedge, and angle trisector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/can-a-regular-heptagon-be-constructed-using-a-compass-straightedge-and-angle-t)

The relevant part of the solution which take from [Akerbeltz's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3539557/583883):

Akerbeltz found this polynum $(y^3-py-q)$ , denote  $\alpha^2 = \frac{4p}{3},  \cos(3θ)=\frac{4q}{\alpha^3} , y=\alpha \cos(\theta)$.

Indeed,
$(\alpha\cos(\theta))^3-p\alpha\cos(\theta)-q=\alpha\frac{4p}{3}\cos^3(\theta)-p\alpha\cos(\theta)-q=\alpha p(\frac{4}{3}\cos^3(\theta)-\cos(\theta))-q=\\
=\frac{\alpha p}{3}\cos(3\theta)-q=\frac{\alpha p}{3}\frac{4q}{\alpha^3}-q=\frac{4pq}{3\alpha^2}-q=\frac{4pq}{3\cdot4p/3}-q=0$

My question is how he knows to take $\alpha^2 = \frac{4p}{3},  cos(3θ)=\frac{4q}{\alpha^3}$ for solving the equation ?

Comment: A Question must be Complete , not referring to other web-sites (or other web-pages) for Core Details. In Case that other Question gets Deleted (or edited) the Question here will be meaningless. I suggest you put in all the relevant Parts here.

Comment: That is well known by the name **"Depressed Cubic Equation"** , which has some well known "Solution Methods" , including with the usage of trigonometric terms like $\cos(\theta)$ & $\cos(3\theta)$ & $\cos^3(\theta)$ , which were modified to work out here.

Comment: You can find out more in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Trigonometric_and_hyperbolic_solutions).